# [Python][Micropython] Im trying to port over a python script to micropython

Tags: python, python-requests, esp8266, micropython

I am trying to port over this script to micropython but im not having any luck. The python code works as intended but i want an esp8266 to monitor the json for the relay status. Im getting OSerror 2 and now Exception once i print it out . Looking for ways to help find out what exception .

**Python Code:**

```
import requests
import binascii
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = "http://apex.local/cgi-bin/status.json"
username = "admin"
password = "1234"
previous_status = None

def login():
    credentials = '{}:{}'.format(username, password)
    encoded_credentials = binascii.b2a_base64(credentials.encode())[:-1].decode()
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(encoded_credentials)}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return response.json()

def get_relay_status(json_data):
    for output in json_data['istat']['outputs']:
        if output['name'] == 'Relay_1':
            return output['status'][0]

def check_status():
    global previous_status
    
    try:
        json_data = login()
        current_status = get_relay_status(json_data)

        if previous_status is not None and previous_status != current_status:
            print(f"Relay status changed to {current_status}")

        previous_status = current_status
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error fetching JSON data: {e}")
while True:
    check_status()
```

**Micropython Code:**

```
import machine
import time
import urequests
import ubinascii

# Wi-Fi credentials
WIFI_SSID = "CREDS"
WIFI_PASSWORD = "CREDS"

# Apex controller credentials
#url = "http://ip.jsontest.com/"
url = "http://apex.local/cgi-bin/status.json"
username = "admin"
password = "1234"
previous_status = None

# LED pin
LED_PIN = 2

# Connect to Wi-Fi network
import network

station = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
station.active(True)
station.connect(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD)
while not station.isconnected():
    time.sleep(1)
print('Wi-Fi connection successful')

# Define LED pin as output
led = machine.Pin(LED_PIN, machine.Pin.OUT)

def login():
    credentials = '{}:{}'.format(username, password)
    encoded_credentials = ubinascii.b2a_base64(credentials.encode())[:-1].decode()
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(encoded_credentials)}

    response = urequests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return response.json(),response
    
# Fetch relay status and toggle LED accordingly
def get_relay_status(json_data):
    for output in json_data['istat']['outputs']:
        if output['name'] == 'Relay_1':
            status = output['status'][0]
            if status == 'ON':
                led.on()
            else:
                led.off()

def check_status():
    global previous_status
    
    try:
        json_data = login()
        current_status = get_relay_status(json_data)
        if previous_status is not None and previous_status != current_status:
          print(current_status)
          previous_status = current_status
    except:
        print("RequestException")
      
while True:
    check_status()
```

Comment: The OSError 2 is due to the apex.local domain not being resolved to an IP address. Because the ESP8266 is not able to resolve the domain name using the DNS server it is configured with.

Comment: I will give it a try using the ip address. Is there a lirary built in to resolve DNS..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended up using . Having some memory issues and watchdog . But this code works for the most part on a wemos d1 mini.

```
import machine
import time
import urequests
import ubinascii
import gc

MIN_HEAP_MEMORY = 10240

# Wi-Fi credentials
WIFI_SSID = "cred"
WIFI_PASSWORD = "cred"

# Apex controller credentials
url = "http://192.168.1.128/cgi-bin/status.json"
username = "admin"
password = "1234"
previous_status = None

# LED pin
LED_PIN = 2
RELAY_PIN = 5

# Connect to Wi-Fi network
import network

station = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
station.active(True)
station.connect(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD)
while not station.isconnected():
    time.sleep(1)
    machine.idle()
print('Wi-Fi connection successful')
ip_address = station.ifconfig()[0]
print(ip_address)

# Define LED pin as output
led_pin = machine.Pin(LED_PIN, machine.Pin.OUT)
relay_pin = machine.Pin(RELAY_PIN, machine.Pin.OUT)

# Precompute headers for requests
credentials = '{}:{}'.format(username, password)
encoded_credentials = ubinascii.b2a_base64(credentials.encode())[:-1].decode()
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(encoded_credentials)}

def login():
    response = urequests.get(url, headers=headers)
    json_data = response.json()
    return json_data

# Fetch relay status and toggle LED accordingly
def get_relay_status(json_data):
    for output in json_data['istat']['outputs']:
        if output['name'] == 'Relay_1':
            status = output['status'][0]
            if status == 'ON':
                
                led_pin.off()
                relay_pin.on()
                control_status = "2"
            else:
                led_pin.on()
                relay_pin.off()
                control_status = "1"
    return status, control_status

def check_status():
    global previous_status
    json_data = login()
    current_status, control_status = get_relay_status(json_data)

    if previous_status is not None and previous_status != current_status:
        control_inject(control_status)
        previous_status = current_status
    else:
        previous_status = current_status

def control_inject(control_status):
    data = {
        "Control_1_state": control_status,
        "noResponse": 1
    }
    data_str = '&'.join(f"{k}={str(v)}" for k, v in data.items())
    print(data_str)

    try:
        # Send the request without checking the response
        urequests.post("http://192.168.1.128/cgi-bin/status.cgi", data=data_str, headers=headers)
    except Exception as e:
        print("If zero all good {e}")

while True:
    try:
        check_status()
        time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception occurred:", e)

    # Force garbage collection and check available heap memory
    gc.collect()
    free_memory = gc.mem_free()
    print("Free heap memory: {} bytes".format(free_memory))

    if free_memory < MIN_HEAP_MEMORY:
        print("Low heap memory, rebooting...")
        machine.reset()

    machine.idle()
```